# Rudin's Proof for Countable union of Countable Sets are Countable.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, set-theory

For reference, the proof for the statement goes like this on the book:
[image]

I follow everything up until right after (17). It seems like we are skipping a small step here so I attempted to fill it up from my reading (the following proof goes right after (17)):

We obtain a sequence from (17), let's call it $S' = \{ x_{n, k} \}_{k}$, which may have duplicates in them if our $\{ E_n \}$ are not pairwise disjoint. Equivalently, by Rudin's definition (see below *), we can treat $S'$ as the range of a (surjective, i.e. onto) function $f: \mathbf{Z^+} \to X$, where $X$ is a set containing $\{ x_{n,k} \}$ defined as $f(1) = x_{11}, f(2) = x_{21}, f(3) = x_{12}, \cdots$ following (17).

Now we note that $S \subseteq S'$ is a set without duplicates. Invoking AoC here (or so I think?), we can find an at most countable subset $T' \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(m) \not \in f(T' - \{ m \})$ for all $m \in T'$. Equivalently, this implies that $f|_{T'}$ is a bijective (1-1 + onto) function. In particular, we have $T' \sim S$ through $f|_{T'}$.

Now the ordering of $T' \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+$ and the element of $T'$ corresponding to the order form a natural bijection (1-1 corrspondance). That is, there exists an at most countable ordering set $T \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $T \sim T'$. By transitivity of equivalence relation, we have $T \sim S$. Now if $T$ is finite, then $T ~ J_n$ where $J_n \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $J_n$ is $\{ 1, \cdots, n \}$ for some $n \in Z^+$. Then $J_n \sim S$ by transitivity, implying $S$ is finite. If $T$ is infinite, then $T$ is countable by Theorem 2.8 (see below **). Then $T \sim \mathbb{Z}^+$, so $S \sim \mathbb{Z}^+$ by transitivity, showing $S$ is countable. This implies that $S$ is at most countable.

Since $E_1 \subseteq S$ is a countable set, hence infinite, we have $S$ to be infinite as well (by an alternative definition of infinite). Since $S$ is at most countable (finite or countable) and infinite, it must be countable.

**Index**:

*[image]
**[image]

**Question**:

Does my proof look right and how can it be simplified (I'm almost sure it could, as although I think this makes more sense to me, but it is pretty long-winded)?

Comment: You don't need the Axiom of Choice to create $T$.  You can explicitly define it by choosing the first (least) index where any particular entry appears.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for reading the proof! I agree that AoC shouldn't be needed in this case. How does the rest of the proof look?

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner, the use of the axiom of (countable) choice occurs earlier in the proof: namely, in forming the table.  Doing so requires not merely each set to be countable, but choosing a specific correspondence with $\mathbb N$ for each of them, simultaneously.  In fact, the result is is not provable without using the axiom of choice. Thus, AC is used at step (16) rather than step (17).

Comment: @RobertShore, note that AC is indeed needed, at the previous step (see above).

Answer (score 1):

I think that using Theorem $2.8$ you can substantially simplify the proof.  (I'm assuming that countable is defined in a way that excludes finite.)  $S$ must be at least countable because it contains a countable set.  The set of all possible indices of $x_{ij}$ is countable, and that set of indices has a subset $T$ (necessarily at most countable by Theorem 2.8) of *unique* preimages of elements of $S$.  The obvious maps $G: \Bbb N \to T$ and $F:T \to S$ compose to give you a bijection $H: \Bbb N \to S$.

Comment: Unfortunately the fact that the index set is countable can not be concluded at this point of the book: Cartesian product preserves size isn't covered at this point... I am not sure if I could use this argument to get Rudin's result.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the proofs in Rudin's that frustrated me the most when I first read it. I will try to explain the part after (17) in details, in case someone might need it in the future.

(17) gives a pretty straightforward way to map $J$ to the elements of $E_n$'s, i.e. $f(1) = x_{11}$, $f(2) = x_{21}$, $f(3) = x_{12}$,... But note that the range of this function is not $S$, since it might contain duplicates, while $S$ is not allowed to. What we can do is to keep only a subset $T$ of $J$ (the same "$T$" that the author used), such that its image under $f$ is indeed $S$. For example, say $f(1) = x_{11} = x_{22} = f(5)$, then $T$ would be the set $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9...\}$.

Since $T \subset J$, and $J$ is clearly countable, if we can show that $T$ is infinite, then it is countable by theorem $2.8$. And by $S \sim T$, so is $S$. So the goal is to show that $T$ is infinite.

Suppose that it is not. Then in (17), $f(T)$ is finite and would have a rightmost value $y$. The reason elements to the right of $y$ not being in $f(T)$ can only be that they are duplicates of something already in $f(T)$, to the left of $y$ in (17). But if we put this element $y$ back in (16), say in row $i$ (i.e. $y \in E_i$}, we can see that the infinitely many values in $E_i$ to the right of $y$ in (16) are duplicates of the finitely many values of $f(T)$ occurring before $y$. But this implies that $E_i$ contains duplicates - a contradiction. Hence $T$ must be infinite.

To illustrate the last point, say we have $y = x_{32}$. Then everything to the right of $x_{32}$ in (17) would not be in $f(T)$. This includes, in (16), $\{x_{33}, x_{34}, x_{35},...\} =: U$. But this means every element of the infinite set $U$ are duplicates of some finitely many elements of $f(T)$ occurring before $x_{32}$ in (17). In particular, this implies $U$, and hence $E_3$, contains duplicates - a contradiction.